# How to bind datasets data to dropdownlist from webservices

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, wsdl, dataset

i am having trouble in populating dataset in DropDownList1 from http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries however, my dropdownlist shows data in char format https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxbyq.jpg and im not sure why.

```
country count = new country(); //from Service

DropDownList1.DataSource = count.GetCountries();
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: check by setting `DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";` before `DataBind()` and also provide what is exactly returned by `count.GetCountries();`

Comment: tried that and got this error System.Web.HttpException: 'DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'.'

Comment: So, we need exact definition returned by `count.GetCountries();`

Comment: According to image, can you test: `count.GetCountries().Tables[0];`

Comment: how do i test that?

Comment: `DropDownList1.DataSource = count.GetCountries().Tables[0];`

Comment: got this error for .Tables[0]
" 'string' does not contain a defination for 'Tables' and no extension method 'Tables' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: what is the signature of `GetCountries` method?

Comment: a string? https://imgur.com/a/2uQaS

Comment: then go with sachin's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your asmx service is providing the xml and you are directly trying to bind it with dropdown, which is incorrect.

you need to convert the xml to dataset and then try to bind.

```
string xmlFile = count.GetCountries();
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
DropDownList1.DataSource = dataSet OR dataSet.Tables[0];
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```